# How to vertically align image middle in <li>?

Tags: html, css

Hell all:
   the below  is the html code, I want to vertically align every image in li , no idea after googling a lot. I can use jquery to set it margin-top according to images' height, but it's 
inconvenient solution.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=GB2312"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        .psdthumb2 ul {
            list-style: none;

        }
        li.qq2{
            height: 400px;
            width: 400px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="psdthumb2">
    <ul>
        <li>111111</li>
        <li class="qq2">
            <img src="http://mat1.qq.com/www/images/allskin/wmlogo.gif">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>222222</li>
        <li class="qq2">
            <img src="http://img11.360buyimg.com/n4/3445/522086b7-dc0a-432c-b027-7b2a80c79f29.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: but what your css classes say?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KGZEq/  please check this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the demo with your updated code:- http://jsbin.com/ozixop/edit#javascript,html,live

you just update your css and add few properties for vertical middle as mentioned below:-

```
    li.qq2{
background-color: red;
display: table-cell;
height: 400px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 400px;
    }
```

Comment: well done, and you let me know jsbin.com which is very helpful with previewing css effects.

Answer (score 2):

```
li.qq2{
   display : table-cell;
   vertical-align : middle;
   text-align : center;
}
```

This should work.

Tested in Chrome, Safari, FF and IE 9.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Heebt/) a working example:

**CSS**

```
.psdthumb2 ul 
{
    list-style: none;
}
li.qq2
{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="psdthumb2">
    <ul>
        <li>111111</li>
        <li class="qq2">
            <img src="http://mat1.qq.com/www/images/allskin/wmlogo.gif">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>222222</li>
        <li class="qq2">
            <img src="http://img11.360buyimg.com/n4/3445/522086b7-dc0a-432c-b027-7b2a80c79f29.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Basically you just need to add  `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` to your css class.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
.qq2 img{vertical-align:middle;}
```

Should work.